# Unity3D C#, add a gameObject from a collision detection to a List

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I wish to add each gameObject that collides with the main gameObject to a List. What would be the best way?
Thank you.

```
void Start()
{
    List <GameObject> selectedObj = new List<GameObject>();
}

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider collider) 
{
    if (collider == true)
    {
        selectedObj.Add(collider);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `selectedObj` is a List of GameObjects, you need to pass in the collider's game object.

```
if (collider == true)
{
    selectedObj.Add(collider.gameObject);
}
```

`gameObject` is an inherited member of the [Collider class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html).